# Comparar y borrar registros de varios documentos con un mismo ID y con autenticación, nodejs y mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy tratando de mejorar el siguiente código:

```
function deletePublication(req, res){
    var publicationId = req.params.id;

    Publication.find({'user': req.user.sub, '_id': publicationId}).remove((err, publicationRemoved) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al borrar la publicación'});

        if(!publicationRemoved) return res.status(404).send({message: 'Error al borrar la publicación'});

        if(publicationRemoved) {
            Comment.find({'publication': publicationId}).remove(err => {
                if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al borrar los comentarios'});

            });

            return res.status(200).send({message: 'Se ha eliminado la publicación'});
        }
        
    });

}
```

Esta función tiene como objetivo borrar una publicación de la base de datos de MongoDB con nodejs.

Cada publicación es creada con su respectivo `_id` y un `user`. El id del usuario lo recojo con el `req.user.sub` en el middleware de autenticación.

Luego, cada publicación también tiene enlazado comentarios. Cada comentario tiene su respectivo `_id`, un `user` que lo crea y un `publication` al que se refiere.

La idea es que al borrar una publicación, con su respectivo `_id` también se borren los comentarios en la base de datos.

Ahora, el código funciona bastante bien.
Al estar logueado con el mismo usuario que creó la publicación, esta efectivamente se borra, y se borran también los comentarios.

El problema es que si no estoy logueado con el mismo usuario que creó la publicación, no solo NO borra la publicación, sino que BORRA todos los comentarios de esa publicación.

Además, sin la parte del find de los comentarios, al querer borrar la publicación sin que coincidan los usuarios, la publicación NO se borra, pero devuelve el mensaje: la publicación ha sido borrada.

Espero se entienda, muchas gracias.